# Is "the funniest interview you will ever see" genuine?

Tags: history, television

There's a funny (or not funny, some might find this offensive) video on You Tube called "[the funniest interview you will ever see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSFWgKl-O-A)". It shows a Dutch talk show host having a fit of uncontrollable laughter while interviewing victims of medical errors, some of which have unusual timbres of voice.

I would like to know if this was a real event, or whether this is a well done comedy sketch which has been relabeled as a real occurrence, or is otherwise not a genuine event, for example something staged/played out by actors.

Comment: I would edit out "funny" part alltogether. Subjectively, I suspect more people would find it offensive than not, given enough thought - and even if not, enough people would find it hurtful that it's not worth having in the Q text.

Comment: Note that the [tag:netherlands] tag is not quite correct, as it's clearly Belgian (Belgian Dutch is a very distinct accent, both in pronunciation and in vocabulary).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out it's a sketch, part of the Flemish series of mockumentaries "[In De Gloria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_de_gloria)".

> In 2006 one of the sketches, "Boemerang" (Boomerang) gained notoriety on YouTube. It features the host of a talk show, "Boemerang", breaking into fits of giggles after hearing the voice of one of his guests, who spoke in a squeaky manner due to a failed tonsillectomy. The video uploader who added English subtitles to the footage implied the footage was real and shortened it especially to remove all indications of it being fake. The full sketch shows the TV host in a supposed archive TV show (hence the title Boomerang) looking back on the infamous moment that got him fired in the past. All people in the footage are actors. The show's host, Erik Hartman, is played by Tom Van Dyck, his two guests Valère and Marijke are portrayed by Lucas Van den Eynde and An Miller.

This is confirmed by [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0235922/):

> One of the sketches ("Boemerang") about a presenter not being able to hold of his laughter during a serious talk with people who are the victims of medical blunders is often mistaken for real (by non-Belgian audiences). It was featured on 'The Tonight Show with Jay Leno' and gained some Internet notoriety through it's popularity on YouTube.